# Pixel Listener (Listener reacting on Pixel changes)

Tags: listener, pixel

i want to create a program that is reacting on some pixels and is increasing a counter when a selected pixel is changed.
Im using the Robot class for it. cause this:

```
Boolean dontcount = false;
Robot robot = new Robot();
while (true) {
if(robot.getPixelColor(900, 900).equals(b)){
    if(dontcount == false){
       counter=counter++;
        dontcount = true;
        System.out.println(counter);
    }
} else {
    dontcount = false;
}
}
```

is killing my pc, i am looking for another way. I guess its possible with listeners. but i got no idea how. any solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code does not compile and doesn't seem to make much sense so I rewrote it. In the future, make sure you have a complete example.

The reason the code is killing your PC is because you should be putting a slight wait time in your while loop to let the computer know it has a chance to breathe. 10ms is plenty.

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Robot;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Robot robot = null;
        try
        {
            robot = new Robot();
        } catch (AWTException e1)
        {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        Color lastPixelColor = null;
        int counter = 0;

        while (true)
        {
            Color pixelColor = robot.getPixelColor(900, 900);
            if (!pixelColor.equals(lastPixelColor))
            {
                counter++;
                System.out.println(counter);
            }

            lastPixelColor = pixelColor;

            try
            {
                // You need to sleep so you don't murder your CPU
                Thread.sleep(10);
            } catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
            }
        }
    }
}
```